# SUM value column where date column is between a two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so i have a date column and an amount column I'm trying to sum the value column where the date is between two values

```
=SUMIFS(V496:V57573,U496:U57573,">"&"01/03/2020",U496:U57596,"<"&"30/04/2020")
```

this is what I'm trying to use where V is the amount and U is the date column but the I don't get the SUM of the amount column I just get a #VALUE! error. what do I need to change in the SUMIFS to get the sum

Comment: all ranges must be same size. If you look at your third range, you typed `U496:U57596` instead of `U496:U57573`

Comment: hadn't spotted that. thanks